# REST proxy to respond with property value

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a property with XML string value. Is it possible to send property value back to client as a response body? If yes, any hint how to do that?

Tried to play with payloadfactory mediator, but it does not seem to work with XML string. As I see it works with plain text string, but requires some wraping XML element anyway.

**UPD**

An alternative solution provided by my colleague even prior the accepted answer is to use OM property with enrich mediator. 
Something like that:

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
<property expression="get-property('myProperty')" name="omProperty" scope="default" type="OM"/>
<enrich description="">
  <source clone="true" property="omProperty" type="property"/>
  <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
<respond/>
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of XML string value which you are using?

Comment: Well, in my case it's soap envelope inside, but dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your property with type OM.

Type 'OM' can be used to set XML property values on the message context. This becomes useful when the expression associated with the property mediator evaluates to an XML node during mediation. With the type attribute set to 'OM' the resulting XML will be converted to an AXIOM OMElement before assigning it to a property.

for example:

My xml:

```
<config>
    <crm>
        <crmUsernamePassword>username:password</crmUsernamePassword>
    </crm>
</config>
```

My property:

```
 <property name="config" expression="get-property('conf:/config.xml')" scope="default" type="OM"/>
 <property name="crmUsernamePassword" expression="$ctx:config//crm/crmUsernamePassword" scope="default"
                  type="STRING"/>
```

In this example i get a property and save it with type="OM". Now i can use Xpath to get any element. you can use Xpath in payloadFactory.

```
 <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
              <soapenv:Body>$1</soapenv:Body>
           </soapenv:Envelope>   
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg expression="$ctx:config" />
        </args>
 </payloadFactory>
 <property name="ContentType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

The result:

```
<config>
    <crm>
        <crmUsernamePassword>username:password</crmUsernamePassword>
    </crm>
</config>
```

Comment: Yeah, yesterday got a similar solution from my colleague, to use OM property, but with enrich mediator instead of payload. As for your solution, do you think it's possible to avoid "xml" wrapper element?

Comment: I test it with my ESB 4.9.0 and its work fine. I don't see any xml or additional tags.